# Рандомное размещение элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript

Дан следующий код

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function compareRandom(a, b) {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

arr.sort(compareRandom);

alert( arr ); // элементы в случайном порядке, например [3,5,1,2,4]
```

Он каждый раз размещает элементы массива в разном порядке, но почему не будет тот же самый эффект, если мы удалим -0.5 из функции?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function compareRandom(a, b) {
  return Math.random();
}

arr.sort(compareRandom);

alert( arr ); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) возвращает значения в интервале [0;1)

Компаратор передаваемый в функцию [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) должен возвращать три варианта значения:

1. <0 - если первое число меньше второго, и менять не нужно
2. 0 - если числа одинаковые
3. >0 - если первое число больше и нужно их поменять

При использовании `return Math.random();` могут вернуться только два варианта 2 и 3, поэтому конечный массив сортируется по убыванию.

При использовании же `Math.random() - 0.5` интервал сдвигается на 0.5 влево и становится равным `[-0.5, 0.5)`, что позволяет получать все три описанных варианта, а, следовательно, получать случайное положение элементов.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда, по идее, массив должен выглядеть так: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 ]?

Comment: @НовиковМаксим, в каком случае?